# can i install dbpedia spotlight on OS windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, spotlight-dbpedia

i would know if i can install dbpedia spotlight on os windows 7 (x64) and set up the DBpedia Spotlight environment on Eclipse.

if i can pleas give me any tutorial , can't find any one talking about dbpedia spotlight and win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia Spotlight runs on the Java Virtual Machine, so it should run on Win7 if it has some implementation of the JVM installed.
http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

If you do have Java, you can just run the service from the jar.

See the quickstart instructions:
https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight#run-your-own-server

Or:
https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Run-from-a-JAR

People have reported success under Windows:
https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/issues/121